# NGINX locations matched not rules

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

at the moment i have an issue with NGINX. I like to serve a static HUGO generated html website. This website is is multi language (en, de) and stored in different folders.

```
└─ /usr/share/nginx/html/my-app/
   ├─ en/
   └─ fr/
```

So i have setup a NGINX configuration to handle en and de content requests in different locations.

```
http {
  ...
  server {
      listen                8080;
      server_name           localhost;
      index                 index.html;
      root                  /usr/share/nginx/html;

        location / {
            root           /usr/share/nginx/html/my-app/en
            index          index.html;
            try_files      $uri $uri/index.html =404;
        }

        location /de/ {
            root           /usr/share/nginx/html/my-app/de
            index          index.html;
            try_files      $uri $uri/index.html =404;
        }

        location /en-us/ {
            root           /usr/share/nginx/html/my-app/en
            index          index.html;
            try_files      $uri $uri/index.html =404;
        }
        ...
 }
```

At this point only `http://localhost:8080` is served by NGINX. So the EN content is served.

But if i request `http://localhost:8080/de` or `http://localhost:8080/de/`  there is always an 404 error. I dont understand why the DE content is not found. There is a 1:1 location - folder matching?!

Also the virtuel path `http://localhost:8080/any-lang` or `http://localhost:8080/any-lang/` is not working. My idea was if the path `any-lang` is requested, NGINX will use the en folder to serve content.

I would be happy about every suggestion or ideas!

Comment: I´ve updated the question for clarification. Also it´s not possible to use diffrent roots for diffrent locations?

Comment: The path to the filename is formed by concatenating the value from `root` with the value `$uri`. So, using  `root /usr/share/nginx/html/my-app/de;` with the URL `/de/index.html` will look for the file at `/usr/share/nginx/html/my-app/de/de/index.html` - notice that `de` appears twice because it appears in both the URL **and** the value for `root`. You need to remove the `/de/` from the end of the `root` statement in the `location /de/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me start with an example

```
server {

    location /images/ {
        root /data;
    }
}
```

When you send a request to the /images/ address, then nginx looks for files in this path to serve it.

```
/data/images/
```

You have 2 choices

**1. The solution given by Richard in the comments (But keep in mind that the folder name must be the same as the address -> `/en-us` folder must be `/usr/share/nginx/html/my-app/en-us`**

**2. Use `alias` instead of `root`**

```
    location / {
        root           /usr/share/nginx/html/my-app/en;
        index          index.html;
        try_files      $uri $uri/index.html =404;
    }

    location /de {
        alias           /usr/share/nginx/html/my-app/de;
        index          index.html;
        try_files      $uri $uri/index.html =404;
    }

    location /en-us {
        alias           /usr/share/nginx/html/my-app/en;
        index          index.html;
        try_files      $uri $uri/index.html =404;
    }
```